# Store result inside a Python class?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

If you run the fit attribute on an instance of a sklearn estimator, for example LinearRegression(), is the result stored somewhere inside the instance of the class? I don't create a new object but I fit the model and can do new things like predict etc.

```
lr = LinearRegression()
lr.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Could I achieve something similar with a class of my own. How could I store the result from run_model() inside the instance of the class?

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'n':[1,1,4,1],
                    'target':[36,8,0,41],
                    'string':['z', 's', 'd', 'h']})

class test:
    
    def __init__(self,
                 dataframe,
                 target,
                 features):
        
        self.dataframe=dataframe
        self.target = target
        self.features = features
    
    def x_y(self):
        X=self.dataframe[self.features]
        y=self.dataframe[[self.target]]
        
        return X, y 
    
    def run_model(self):
        X, y = self.x_y()
        list_result = X.n*4
        return list_result
        

a = test(dataframe=data, target='target', features=['n','string'])     
a.run_model()

Output:
0     4
1     4
2    16
3     4
Name: n, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Use a `@classmethod` `def` and save the value within to `cls.value`, that is what I do. Then you can get the value with `test.value`. Not sure if this is the best method but its what I use.

Comment: @Henrik do you wan to use it as a scikit learn object. Or is just a question more general?

Comment: @LucasM.Uriarte well, a sort of scikit learn object is what I’m aiming for, further down the road. Right now all input is valuable.

Comment: @and you need an exmaple of how to do that? just storing the values in a instance attribute is not enough?

Comment: @LucasM.Uriarte I would be grateful for an example, yes

Comment: @Henrik I have make an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is a basic example

```py
class test:
    
    def __init__(self,
                 dataframe,
                 target,
                 features):
        
        self.dataframe=dataframe
        self.target = target
        self.features = features
        self.run_model_results = None # is not obligatory but I advice to declare your attribute in the constructor 
    
    def x_y(self):
        X=self.dataframe[self.features]
        y=self.dataframe[[self.target]]
        
        return X, y 
    
    def run_model(self):
        X, y = self.x_y()
        list_result = X.n*4
        self.run_model_results = list_result  # store values in your attribute
        return list_result

    def square_model_result(self):
        
        if self.run_model_results is not None: # this if only if you declare your attribute in the init
            return  self.run_model_results**2  # reuse your results here or anywere
        else:
            print("run model first")

a = test(dataframe=data, target='target', features=['n','string'])     
a.run_model()  
a.square_model_result()
```

The last method have use the values you have store to produce its result

```
0     16
1     16
2    256
3     16
```